# flatpak define dependency in manifest

Tags: flatpak, flatpak-builder

How to add another flatpak packages as a dependency to my app?

I want my app to be able to call mpv, so it would be nice to install `io.mpv.Mpv` along with my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. The classical way is to write the mpv compilation rule in your application manifest so that it can then be used by your application. You can find the mpv manifest [here](https://github.com/flathub/io.mpv.Mpv/blob/master/io.mpv.Mpv.yml), so that you can include/adapt this code for your application manifest.